# Como cambiar con CSS el color de los option de un select teniendo el focus en cada elemento

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Logre cambiar el color de los option cuando están seleccionados y sacando el foco del select.

```
select > option:checked { 
background-color: #001f3f;
color: white;
```

}

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando ingreso al select o le doy el foco el color cambia a turquesa intente cambiarlo con esto pero nada.

```
select > option:focus { 
background-color: #001f3f;
color: white;
```

}

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Probaste agregando la etiqueta "!important" en el color?

Comment: Si lo probé y nada sigue con ese color turquesa. Cuando le quito el foco o salgo del select recién cambia al azul que quiero pero ingresando al select se cambia el color.

Comment: Ese color es propio del navegador, si ejecutas tu código en otros navegadores vas a ver que cambia un poco. No es tu código. Por acá hay una entrada similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457849/how-to-remove-the-border-highlight-on-an-input-text-element

Answer (score 0):

lo hice asi y funciona:

```
option, select { 
    background-color: #001f3f;
    color: white;  
}
```

y se ve azul siempre, si no te funciona importa el archivo normalize.css, esta en la web y soluciona muchos errores extraños en css

Comment: SI pero cuando le das clic en el select cambia el option seleccionado a turquesa.

Comment: pues tiene que haber algun problema en otro lado, pone todo el codigo tanto en HTML como en CSS que si no tenemos que suponer que no hay nada mas que eso.